# How to get the Application Process ID in Windows Phone 8.1 Store Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Application and there is a need to get the Application Process ID from code. Any API with which I can get that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) followed by `DuplicateHandle` (and later `CloseHandle`) but I'm curious what you need it for... there's not much you can do with it in a Store app so maybe this won't complete your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to print the Process ID in the log statements that  DUMP TO A FILE. I tried to call the function :  GetCurrentProcess() from a page defined in my Ui code, but its throwing compilation error.( Not able to find such API). There is no Process class in System.Diagnostics also. Is the API not supported in WP 8.1? It would be helpful if you can provide a code snippet example of how to access the GetCurrentprocess() API from a Page.

Comment: It is a Win32 API so you either need to write a C++ wrapper or use P/Invoke (easier to search the web than ask on SO for samples there). But even in the log file, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: I tried using 
'[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();'
inside my UI class, but when tried to access GetCurrentProcess() from code it throwed DllNotFoundException, ie cannot find Kernal32
.dll. Tried the same in WinRT component but the same exception got thrown.

Comment: Got the solution : used GetCurrentprocessId() in api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll lib instead of using kernal32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution.

The Dll's for Desktop apps and Phone apps are different though the function names will be same.

When tried to import Kernal.dll lib in WIn Phone 8.1 and used p/invoke code, an exception, DllNotFoundException will be thrown. Instead in Win Phone 8.1 instead use "api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll"

To get the process ID in Win Phone 8.1 :

1)Create binding to WIN32 lib:

```
[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, PreserveSig = true)]
    internal static extern uint GetCurrentProcessId();
```

2)Call the function:

```
  uint id= GetCurrentProcessId();
```

For the complete set of Win Phone 8 supported API's see the MSDN link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662956(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ListofsupportedWin32APIs